# twitter typeahead.js - add clickable font awesome icon to results list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, typeahead.js

I would like to customize typeahead / bloodhound's display of the results list by adding a clickable font awesome icon. The use case is to allow users to initiate editing of one of the result items, rather than selecting it.

Is this possible?

I have added this suggestion template:

```
    suggestion: function(el){
     return '<div><strong>' + el.value + '</strong>' + 
    '<span style=display:inline-block; float:right;">
    <a href="test.php"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><span></div>'},
}
```

This displays the icon and makes it clickable, but the icon is displayed right next to the el.value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not use inline styles, instead add a new class definition:

```
    .tt-suggestion span {
      display: : inline-block;
      float: right;
     }
```

and the icon is displayed correctly, aligned at the end of the suggestion row.